# Redux managing a string always returns "undefined"

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a search box, in which when I type something I trigger onChange, and in onChange I call my redux function which should set the "showSearchQuery" in redux store to the string that is passed, but instead I always get "undefined". Can anyone help?

Here are the components/redux code in question:

search box component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './search-box.styles.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setShowSearchQuery } from '../../redux/actions/index';

class SearchBox extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      searchQuery: '',
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    // console.log('EVENT TARGET VAL', event.target.value);
    this.setState({ searchQuery: event.target.value });
    let query = this.state.searchQuery;
    setShowSearchQuery(query);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type='search'
        placeholder={'Search by title'}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    showSearchQuery: state.showSearchQuery,
    loading: state.loading,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setShowSearchQuery })(SearchBox);
```

action:

```
export const setShowSearchQuery = (data) => {
  return {
    type: SET_SHOW_SEARCH_QUERY_SUCCESS,
    data,
  };
};
```

reducer:

```
import { setShowSearchQueryUtil } from './shows.utils';


 case SET_SHOW_SEARCH_QUERY_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        showSearchQuery: setShowSearchQueryUtil(action.data),
        loading: false,
      };
```

utils function:

```
export const setShowSearchQueryUtil = (query) => {
  return query;
};
```

Now whereever I try to access "showSearchQuery" I always get undefined.

Comment: `setShowSearchQuery` should come from props hence it should be `this.props. setShowSearchQuery(query)` inside `handleChange`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for your help! I can't believe I forgot this :D
It works now, but "showSearchQuery" is now always 1 character behind (for example if "test" is typed in the input, the state is "tes". if its "test1" its "test").

Comment: Would you mind accepting it if I put it as an answer?

Comment: Of course not, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Not sure why this is happening with the characters. If you could make a small demo it might help but please ask it in a new thread as it is a different question from the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setShowSearchQuery` should come from props hence it should be `this.props. setShowSearchQuery(query)` inside `handleChange` event.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    // console.log('EVENT TARGET VAL', event.target.value);
    this.setState({ searchQuery: event.target.value });
    let query = this.state.searchQuery;
    this.props.setShowSearchQuery(query);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Import statement is correct

```
import { setShowSearchQuery } from '../../redux/actions/index';
```

In handleChange:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    // console.log('EVENT TARGET VAL', event.target.value);
    this.setState({ searchQuery: event.target.value });
    let query = this.state.searchQuery;
    this.props.setShowSearchQuery(query);
  };
```

and

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        setShowSearchQuery: data => {
            dispatch(setShowSearchQuery(data));
        }
    };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    showSearchQuery: state.showSearchQuery,
    loading: state.loading,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBox);
```